# Writing code for dict and defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have the following problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def give_it_to_me(d):
    # This will crash if key 'it' does not exist
    return d['it']

def give_it2_to_me(d):
    # This will never crash, but does not trigger the default value in defaultdict
    return d.get('it2')

d1 = defaultdict(int)
d2 = { 'it' : 55 }

print give_it_to_me(d1)
print give_it_to_me(d2)

print give_it2_to_me(d1)
print give_it2_to_me(d2)
```

As you can see in the comments, it seems impossible to write a version of `give_it_to_me` which:

1. Does never crash
2. Triggers the default value for `defaultdict`s

Or am I wrong?

Comment: How about using `try return d['it']   except KeyError: return None` ?

Comment: It won't crash, it will throw an exception. Which you can catch, right?

Comment: @falsetru: yep, that seems the right solution. Can you put it into an answer? Anyway, it bugs me that `d.get('it')` does not work as expected for a `defaultdict`. As expected *by me* at least: accessing a key in a defaultdict should return the default value, no matter if you are accessing the key like this `d['it']` or like this `d.get('it')`

Comment: @gonvaled: You just have to adjust your expectation. `get` is implemented such that when it only receives one parameter, the default value is `None`. Also, read [the documentation for defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It says right there: "Note that __missing__() is not called for any operations besides __getitem__(). This means that get() will, like normal dictionaries, return None as a default rather than using default_factory."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need a bit more code in your `give_it_to_me` function.

Use a `try` `except` statement to check for an existing key.

For example:

```
def give_it_to_me(d):
    # This won't crash if key 'it' does not exist in a normal dict.
    # It returns just None in that case.
    # It returns the default value of an defaultdict if the key is not found.
    try:
        return d['it']
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Comment: @gonvaled: Did you try his solution? When `d` is a `defaultdict`, `d['it']` uses the default value. When `d` is a regular dict and `'it'` isn't present, it returns `None`. This is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: But nevertheless, take a look at my comment above. Do you know why defaultdict is implemented so that `.get` does not work *as expected*?

Answer (score 1):

Use `try .. except`:

```
try
    return d['it']
except KeyError:
    return None
```

**Why `defaultdict.get` does not work as expected**:

`defaultdict` is implemented using [__missing__](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__missing__#mapping-types-dict) method. `__missing__` method is only called by `dict[k]` (or `dict.__getitem__(k)`) when the key `k` is not in a dictionary.

[`defaultdict.__missing__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__) also mention that:

> Note that `__missing__()` is not called for any operations besides
>   `__getitem__()`. This means that `get()` will, like normal dictionaries, return None as a default rather than using [`default_factory`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that part of the documentation. I still think this is a bit counter-intuitive: the `defaultdict` has, after all, a default value, as defined by the `default_factory`. That should also be used by `.get` imho. I do not see the rationale of not using the factory with `.get`.

Comment: @gonvaled, Think about `d = defaultdict(int); d.get(1, 2)`. If `dict.get` was implemented to call `__missing__`, d would an entry with 1 as key, and 0 as value. IMHO, that's normally an unexpected side effec.